# Discord Message Object Variables Aren't Being Returned Correctly

Tags: discord, discord.io

So, for some reason the variables for the message object are not being returned correctly, specifically, I want to get the timestamp of the message, but every time I use `messageObj.timestamp` it returns it as undefined. Despite the fact that using `logger.info(messageObj)` returns an array with timestamp being one of the variables, and it has the correct timestamp.

Below is my code, and result that shows my issue:

```
    var BigD = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');



// Configure Logger

logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';

// Init bot

var bot = new BigD.Client({
    token: auth.token,
    autorun: true
});

bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Burners are heated up and ready sir!');
    logger.info('Currently, my name is: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});

bot.on('message', (userName, userID, channelID, messageContent, messageObj) => {
    logger.info(messageObj);
    logger.info(messageObj.t);
    logger.info(messageObj.s);
    logger.info(messageObj.op);
    logger.info(messageObj.type);
    logger.info(messageObj.tts);
    logger.info(messageObj.timestamp);
    logger.info(messageObj.pinned);
    logger.info(messageObj.nonce);
    logger.info(messageObj.mentions);
    logger.info(messageObj.mention_roles);
    logger.info(messageObj.mention_everyone);
    logger.info(messageObj.id);
    logger.info(messageObj.embeds);
    logger.info(messageObj.edited_timestamp);
    logger.info(messageObj.content);
    logger.info(messageObj.channel_id);
    logger.info(messageObj.username);
    logger.info(messageObj.id); //'id' is twice, but it doesn't have the same value in the full printed version, could this be an indication of a separate container variable/method?
    logger.info(messageObj.discriminator);
    logger.info(messageObj.avatar);
    logger.info(messageObj.attachments);
});
```

This is what is returned in CMD:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a discord.js question. In discord.js there is no `messageObj.t` that returns `MESSAGE_CREATE`

Comment: This is specifically for bots, `messageObj` is the variable name for the `Message` class object that is sent when the `Message Created` event is fired. I'm looking specifically for why the `Message` object variables aren't calling correctly.

Comment: Yeah but Discord.JS is a framework. And the tag should only be used if you are using that framework. What framework are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/discord.js "Discord.js is a node.js module that allows the developer to interact with the Discord API. Use this tag for questions about the usage of discord.js, not for questions regarding the Discord API or Discord in general."

Comment: It appears I'm using discord.io to interact with discord.

Comment: I'm not sure how discord.io works, but in terms of the raw data receieved from Discord, the timestamp for a MESSAGE_CREATE event will be inside the internal payload, located under and object with the key `d`

Does something like `messageObj.d` yield anything? Seeing that you only seem to be able to access the data from the actual raw payload and not the event data.

Comment: Using messageObj.d does, in fact return what I want. Why does it? Is d a library contained inside the message class which holds the values of the message itself? What about obtaining the author values?

Answer (score 0):

If you print out that `messageObj` you will get a javascript object that looks like this

```
{ t: 'MESSAGE_CREATE',
  s: 4,
  op: 0,
  d:
   { type: 0,
     tts: false,
     timestamp: '2018-05-18T17:26:28.177000+00:00',
     pinned: false,
     nonce: '447087599983525888',
     mentions: [],
     mention_roles: [],
  ...
```

So you can access it like

```
messageObj.d.timestamp
```

Now, as for why you're having the issue, you've confused what the last parameter is for `Client#on`. You named it `messageObj` and refer to it as a "message", which can be correct in a sense since it's still a message sent to discord, but it is an `Event` object and not a `Message` object.

A `Message` object looks like this

```
{ attachments: [],
  tts: false,
  embeds: [],
  timestamp: '2018-05-18T02:14:14.944000+00:00',
  mention_everyone: false,
  id: '446858023168638976',
  ....
```

Which would be accessed the way you attempted.